# "aws s3 ls" command throwing "InvalidRequest" error message. How to solve it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

After I run `aws s3 ls` command I get below error message:-

> A client error (InvalidRequest) occurred when calling the ListBuckets
>   operation: You are attempting to operate on a bucket in a region that
>   requires Signature Version 4. You can fix this issue by explicitly
>   providing the correct region location using the --region argument, the
>   AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable, or the region variable in the
>   AWS CLI configuration file. You can get the bucket's location by
>   running "aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET".

Below are more details and my findings that may help to answer the question:-

- The command is being executed from an EC2 Instance running in `ap-south-1` region.
- [This](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html) Amazon doc says that new region created after Jan 30 2014 only support Signature Version 4.
- As suggested by error message I tried giving command `aws --region ap-south-1 s3 ls` but the this command also gives the same error message.
- I have run `yum update` and the AWS CLI version is latest which is `aws-cli/1.10.33 Python/2.7.10 Linux/4.4.11-23.53.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.4.23`
- The above `aws s3 ls` command works absolutely fine and lists the buckets if it is executed from an us-east-1 instance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to update `aws cli` to latest version(v1.11.84 at the time of writing).

If `yum update` is not working then try following this [Guide to install AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html)

The reason behind this error is, in newer regions AWS S3 doesn't support Lower Signature Version.

Comment: To expand on this answer, the version of the AWS CLI in package repositories is often out of date and is really best installed by downloading it from AWS.

Comment: Thanks it worked. These are the steps that I took:- 1> `sudo yum remove aws-cli` 2> `sudo pip install awscli`

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Comment: I have a Mac and upgrading my aws-cli unfortunately did not solve this issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac do `sudo pip install awscli` and that should fix the issue.

Comment: The exact same `pip install` command worked for me on Amazon Linux AMI. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: Upgrading my aws-cli unfortunately did not solve this issue for me.